# Использование цикла в JS

Tags: jquery

Понимаю, что задача весьма тривиальная... только никак не получается
Есть несколько таблиц. Есть JS с функцией разбивки и поиска. Стыковка происходит по ID таблицы.

```
var TableData = function () {
    "use strict";

    var runDataTable_map = function () {

        var oTable = $('#map1').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                    "aTargets": [0]
                }],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                "sSearch": "",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "",
                    "sNext": ""
                }
            },
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "Все"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
        });
        $('#map1_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control input-sm").attr("placeholder", "Поиск");
        // modify table search input
        $('#map1_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("m-wrap");
        // modify table per page dropdown        
    };    

    return {
        init: function () {
            runDataTable_map();
        }
    };
}();
```

где #map1 - это ID таблицы. 
Так вот при использовании 2 и более таблиц работает он только на первой. Соответственно, приходится добавлять весь скрипт отдельно для каждой. Думал оптимизировать это дело с использованием перебора значений цикла, но все безуспешно: не соображу, как вместо "1" воткнуть цикл

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно, если у таблиц id map1, map2, map3....

```
 var TableData = function () {
    "use strict";

    var runDataTable_map = function (tables) {
        var oTable = {}; 
        tables.forEach(function(e,k,t){
            oTable[k] = $('#map'+(k+1)).dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                    "aTargets": [0]
                }],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                    "sSearch": "",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sPrevious": "",
                        "sNext": ""
                    }
                },
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "Все"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
            });
            $('#map'+(k+1)+'_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control input-sm").attr("placeholder", "Поиск");
            $('#map'+(k+1)+'_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("m-wrap");
        }   
    };    

    return {
        init: function () {
            let tables = document.querySelectorAll('.dataTable');
            runDataTable_map(tables);
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: `$('[id^="map"]')` )

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо за отклик... к сожалению не успешно. Была пропущена скобка закрывающая, тем не менее все равно не сработало. К своему стыду я в JS делитант и скорее всего ошибаюсь, но откуда берется значение переменной k, разве не нужно задать ее исходное значение?

Comment: @OlegKasumoff k это индекс эл-та массив tables. Что именно не успешно? Ошибки есть или просто не работает?

Comment: @InDevX Просто не работает.

Comment: @OlegKasumoff можете сюда или на какой-нибудь jsfiddle.net добавить минимальный воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: @InDevX Так и не смог воспроизвести пример. (( Могу лишь сказать, что использую плагин https://datatables.net/ в проекте на фреймворке bootstrap и в связке оно работает каждая отдельная функция на отдельную таблицу.

Comment: Ну, так-то если таблицы ничем не отличаются то можно всем таблицам дать одинаковый клас, и просто через этот клас прописать, аля `$('.myTable').dataTable({...` и оно сразу ко всем применить должно плагин

Comment: @InDevX Насчет `var oTable = $('.myTable').dataTable({` понятно, а вот с `$('#map1_wrapper .dataTables_...` как быть? Просто `$('.myTable_wrapper... ` ведь не поменяешь ))

Comment: `...$('[id$="_wrapper"] .dataTables_filter input')...$('[id$="_wrapper"] .dataTables_filter select')...`

Answer (score 0):

Решено! Все оказалось просто... В данном случае максимальное кол-во таблиц - 99.

```
var TableData = function () {
    "use strict";
    var runDataTable_example = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var oTable = $('#map' + i).dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        "aTargets": [0]
                    }],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                    "sSearch": "",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sPrevious": "",
                        "sNext": ""
                    }
                },
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "Все"] // change per page values here
                ],
                // set the initial value
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
            });
            $('#map' + i + '_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control input-sm").attr("placeholder", "Поиск");
            // modify table search input
            $('#map' + i + '_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("m-wrap");
            // modify table per page dropdown        
        }
    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            runDataTable_example();
        }
    };
}();
```

Спасибо всем участникам! С наступающим!